# Copying Apache v2 files to another Apache v2 project

Tags: apache-2.0

What is the proper approach for copying a file from an Apache v2 licensed project to a different Apache v2 project?

If I understand, I would keep the header license attribution for the source project, but would I add a second license header to the file for the Apache v2 licenses project the file is copied into?

Answer (score 2):

Your obligations when copying a file from an Apache v2 licensed project are the same, regardless of the license of the target project. You have to retain the license, copyrights and any additional attributions from the NOTICE file.

When the target project also uses the Apache v2 license, then you can merge the two NOTICE files and you only have to have a single copy of the license text and the license header in the source files.